# Cannot create a row of size 8091 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I want to save file to my SQL Server; the column type is `varbinary(max)`.

When I try to save, I get an error:

> Cannot create a row of size 8091 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

This is the code

```
Using fs As New IO.FileStream(OpenFileDialog2.FileName, IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read)
    If fs.Length <= Int32.MaxValue Then
        Dim bytes(CInt(fs.Length - 1)) As Byte
        fs.Read(bytes, 0, CInt(fs.Length))

        Dim docfile As New SqlParameter("@d39", SqlDbType.VarBinary)
        docfile.Value = bytes

        cmd.Parameters.Add(docfile)
    End If
End Using
```

**from OP's comment**: Table Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[empolyee] (
    [Emp_code] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[arabicname] [nchar](250) NOT NULL
    ,[worktime] [nvarchar](250) NULL
    ,[filedata] [varbinary](max) NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [PK_empolyee] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Emp_code] ASC) WITH (
        PAD_INDEX = OFF
        ,STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF
        ,IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF
        ,ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON
        ,ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON
        ) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY] GO
```

Comment: Please show us the **table structure** of that table you're inserting your data into ....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Row size greater than allowable maximum row size of 8060](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631546/entity-framework-row-size-greater-than-allowable-maximum-row-size-of-8060)

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the name of the column FileData, I think you trying to store a file in the database.

If this is correct, change the column type to blob.

```
TINYBLOB    L+1 bytes, where L < 28     256 bytes
BLOB        L+2 bytes, where L < 216    65 kilobytes
MEDIUMBLOB  L+3 bytes, where L < 224    16 megabytes
LONGBLOB    L+4 bytes, where L < 232    4 gigabytes
```

If you are managing big files you also need to check your sql configuration for the maximum packet size or you will have errors when trying to store large files.