# SQL Server : creating row bigger than 8060 bytes on table update

Tags: c#, sql-server

When updating a column on my table from `varchar(6)` to `varchar(10)` using Database Telerik, SQL Server throws this error:

> SQL exception on 'ALTER TABLE [Bin] ALTER COLUMN [bin_code] varchar(10) NOT NULL' : Cannot create a row of size 8061 which is greater than the allowable maximum row size of 8060.

The problem is, the table usually has 30 bytes of length, since it's composed by one `varchar` column and some `int` and foreign Keys.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bin]
(
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [bin_code] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [icc_modulus_size] [int] NOT NULL,
    [icc_public_exponent] [int] NOT NULL,
    [icc_generation_counter] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_brand] [int] NOT NULL,
    [id_issuer] [int] NOT NULL,

)
```

(not included the foreign key part)

I know that a row in SQL can't exceed the length of 8060, but the problem is why it's trying to create this when updating the table?

Comment: I'm guessing that isn't your full DDL.

Comment: Did you try to disable the key, alter the column and then establishing the key?

Comment: Did the table once have additional columns?  Have you tried ALTER TABLE REBUILD on the table?

Comment: Are you sure it's `dbo.Bin` that your unqualified `[Bin]` picks up?

Comment: @GSerg yes, because it's the only object Bin in the database, also the Telerik is building this script alone based on the model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework - Row size greater than allowable maximum row size of 8060](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7631546/11683)